# Minimum Spanning tree subgraph

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree

I am going through all the exercises in my book for revision of a class test next week, and i am really confused about this sub-graph question.

Currently my thinking leads me to believe that since we already have a minimum spanning tree G therefore since we have sub-nodes present in that minimum spanning tree, a G' has to exist. As far as the condition goes, i'm at a bit of a loss.

> A graph X′ is a sub-graph of graph X if the node and edge sets of X′
>   are subsets of the node and edge sets of X respectively. Let us have
>   (V,T) as a minimum spanning tree of G and  G′=(V′,E′) be a connected
>   sub-graph of G.
>
> (a)  Prove that (V′,E′∩T) is a sub-graph of a minimum spanning tree of G′.
>
> (b) Under what condition is (V′,E′∩T) a minimum spanning tree of G′?
>   Prove your claim.

thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not really a programming question, it would fit more on [math.stackexhange](http://math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: well there is a tag for minimum spanning tree, i don't see why it isn't just because it doesn't contain code. It contains a requirement for pseudocode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for *(a)*

I don't really get the question ... can you explain ?

for *(b)*

I think it's if

for every `e=(u,v)` in `T`  if `u in V'` and `v in V'` then `e in E`

then we have `(V′,E′∩T)` is a minimum spanning tree of `G'`.

Coz :

1. If some `e` that has `e=(u,v)` in `T`  if `u in V'` and `v in V'` but not `in E'`, then
   `(V′,E′∩T)` is not connected at all. It certainly can't be a spanning tree of `G'`
2. If the condition stands, but `(V′,E′∩T)` is not a spanning tree of `G'`, then `G'` has a spanning tree with less cost, let's say it's `Tg`. We can construct a spanning tree `T'` of `G` with less cost than `T`, by: (i) remove every `e=(u,v) , u in V' and v in V' and e in T` from `T` (ii) add every `e=(u,v) , u in V' and v in V' and e in Tg`  . The resulting graph is a spanning tree of `G` (because it's connected while having the same number of edges of `T`) and has less cost than `T`. So it can never happen since we already know `T` is a minimul spanning tree of `T`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i think question a is basically asking for evidence of a subgraph contained in G' with v', e'

Comment: This criterion says that only subgraphs defined by their vertex subsets and with canonical inclusion of edges (all of them dragged in that can be) have the property. This is too restrictive. Other subgraphs also satisfy the predicate in (b).

Answer (score 3):

(a) As I mentioned in a comment (V', E' ∩ T) may contain more than one component. In general, a minimal spanning tree of G' will need more edges. The question is whether there's ever some edge already given in E' ∩ T that can ever go unused. So, we can rephrase the question as the existence of a minimal spanning tree (V', T') for G' such that E' ∩ T ⊂ T'.

Here's a proof that uses [Kruskal's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskals%27s_algorithm) and its proof of correctness. The enumeration of edges by weight in Kruskal's algorithm is not deterministic. Although edges are sorted by weight, the enumeration in non-deterministic on edges of equal weight. Yet for every spanning tree, there's some monotonic enumeration of the edges that yields the minimal spanning tree (V,T). Let E_x be the set of all edges of weight x. For an ordering, pick any order such that all edges in E_x ∩ T come before those in E_x \ T. None of the edges in E_x ∩ T form a cycle in the step in Kruskal's algorithm where they are examined, because they appear in the ultimate minimal spanning tree. It doesn't matter what order they appear in, either, since the order wouldn't change the non-existence of a cycle. Then, all the edges in E_x \ T are discarded because they would form cycles, since they don't appear in T. Thus there's always some ordering for the edges E that yields the minimal tree (V,T).

For the next step, we run Kruskal's algorithm again on G' using an ordering that would yield our given minimal spanning tree of G. Call this tree (V', T'). The key property here is that when we do this, all the edges in E' ∩ T are added before any other edges. To the contrary, suppose that some edge t ∈ E' ∩ T would be rejected in the run on G' because it formed a cycle. That would mean that some chain C had already formed a connection between two components that edge t was the first to connect when computing (V,T). If so, that same chain would have connected those components in the original run, which they did not. Now consider the state of the Kruskal's algorithm on G' at the point immediately after adding the edge in E_x ∩ T to the tree-in-progress. Anything that Kruskal's algorithm adds afterward is added on, so that E_x ∩ T ⊂ T'.

(b) This part is mostly a corollary to part (a), namely, the observation that the edge set E' ∩ T is always a valid state at some point of a run of Kruskal's algorithm. Thus, if the algorithm is done at that point, that is, the set of edges is exhausted, then E' ∩ T is exactly the edges of the minimal spanning tree. The condition is that the algorithm ends when it's in this state, thus when (V',  E' ∩ T) is connected, the Kruskal's algorithm terminates and (V',  E' ∩ T) is a minimal spanning tree. Conversely, if (V',  E' ∩ T) is a minimal spanning tree, then it's necessarily connected.

Comment: upvote. wish i had gotten here 21 hours ago. i could have used that bounty :)

Comment: @davec Thanks. The most interesting thing about this problem is that all the new edges needed to connect up the fragments of the larger spanning tree are necessarily larger than anything in the fragment. That's an interesting property. It might be strong enough that the converse is also true, namely, if for a given spanning tree, if every connected subgraph G' the added edges are similarly ordered, then the spanning tree is minimal. I'm not sure if this is true, however.

Comment: one thing that concerned me what when you said "the minimal spanning tree (V,T)" - are you accounting for the fact there may be more than one minimal spanning tree in a given graph?

Comment: @davec Sure; it's the reason that the proof is as long as it is. The questions are relative to the tree `(V,T)` that we're given. We are only guaranteed that one particular edge ordering for Kruskal's algorithm yields the edges `T` in the spanning tree; any other ordering might lead to another tree. Those other orderings, likewise, need not yield the tree `(V',E'&cap;T)` when running on the subset graph G'. The use of the word "the" only refers to it as the "the argument" that we're given as a parameter to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Part 'a' follows almost immediately from the observation that a minimum spanning tree (such as `(V,T)`) is indeed minimal!   Here's a sketch of one part of the proof:

Assume for contradiction that `(V′,E′∩T)` is *not* minimal.  This would mean that there is some `e in E′∩T` that we could remove while still preserving its connectivity.  That would imply that `e` could also be removed from T, which it clearly cannot be, because `T` is minimal.

For Part 'b', I think lavin has offered a decent solution.  Hope this helps some.

Comment: thank you i had not thought of that logic, i was going more for the fact that if it already had edges in the tree and the sub-graph was to have the ∩ of those edges, then it should also be a sub-graph, but your logic seems more simple to follow.

Comment: I think I follow.  The important observation is that there is no such `e` in (V′,E′∩T), which is effectively the minimality condition for `G′`.

Comment: This answer doesn't work. (V', E'∩T) need not be a tree, but rather it might be a forest containing multiple disconnected tree components. Removing edges would indeed increase the number of components, but you can't assume that (V', E'∩T) has only one component to begin with.

Comment: You're quite right.  The fact that we were only trying to establish it as a subgraph should still take care of that, no?

Comment: @Gian I can't figure out what you're asking.

Comment: I'm suggesting that the step of the proof I sketched is still helpful in establishing the first property (i.e., that you obtain a subgraph), unless I've missed something.

Comment: how did this win the bounty? 

it's incorrect. in part A you are assuming that (V', E'∩T) is connected (when you say "while still preserving its connectivity")



this is not a valid assumption and invalidates the whole idea



specifically, when you perform intersection E'∩T, the resulting set might not connect all of the vertices in V′ just because E' connected them. This is what eh9 means by disconnected components

Comment: Beats me, ask the poster :) The point is that it will not create any *more* disconnected components.  "Preserving connectivity" in this case means "preserving the connectivity of all connected components". Keep in mind that I offered this as a sketch of *one step* to establish only the first property. There is obviously more work required for the proof, but I wasn't going to do his homework for him.

Answer (score 1):

i offer an informal tl;dr version for the impatient :) eh9 deserves the bounty

a - there exists some spanning tree for v' formed by T's intersection with all the edges v' could have. E' ∩ T is necesarily a subset of this

b - the condition is when (V', E' ∩ T) is connected. any non minimal edges and cycles in E' are discarded by the intersection with T, and any the remaining minimal connected graph is a MST

Comment: Regarding a), isn't that what eh9 was contradicting earlier? That filtering the edges of `T` such that they terminate in `V'` doesn't necessarily result in a spanning tree of `G'`? If I understood correctly, it isn't even necessarily a connected graph.